# Change background colour of Quick Look / VIew?

Tags: finder

Selecting an image in finder and pressing space to bring up Quick Look / View is something I use all the time.

However I'd prefer a med grey background colour as I work allot with transparent png's with white borders - so currently its hard to so see the edges.

Anyone know of a setting / app / method for setting this?

osx 10.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Switch to Fullscreen mode, there you have a black background color.

[image]

And then your background is black:

[image]

Comment: Ah of course! And I just googled you can hold Option + Space to open Quick View in fullscreen.